# Full Spectrum LED (400nm to 840nm) vs Grow Light LED (RED+BLUE)

Tags: aquarium, community-aquarium, aquatic-plants, plants, lighting

I'm planning to buy lights for my planted aquarium tank. After a small research I found that regular lights are not suited for growing plants.
Beacuse they need **BLUE** for leaf growth and **RED** for stem elongation. 
In stores I found 2 variants of this lights. One was actually a combination of both the LED's and other was simply called Full Spectrum LED.
Can any one please suggest me which one is good for my 6 gallon tank?

I got these plants:

- *Eleocharis paravula* (Japanese)
- *Ludwigia sp.* (Mini Red)
- *Elatine triandra*

For reference (www.ebay.in):

- [Full Spectrum LED](http://www.ebay.in/itm/10-Pcs-3w-Full-Spectrum-LED-Taiwan-Epistar-Indoor-Plant-Grow-Light-400nm-840nm-/172421286248?hash=item28251c0968:g:AMwAAOSwz2lXCiSw)
- [Grow Light LED](http://www.ebay.in/itm/LED-Full-Spectrum-IR-UV-Grow-Light-14W-28-SMD-LEDs-E27-Plant-Flower-Grow-Bulb-/252917131903?hash=item3ae3092a7f:g:TG4AAOSwjqVZCYfK)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think the lights you mention is made for fish tanks. This doesn't mean they can't be used but a better choice would be to try finding lighting made for fish tanks. Maybe ask for some advice from shops that are selling aquarium equipment to find some lighting made for fish tanks that fits the size of your tank.

I know this doesn't answer your question fully but this is my advice to you.

Comment: I got the answer for this same question from Stack overflow Electrical Engineering.https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/304485/full-spectrum-led400nm840nm-vs-grow-light-led-redblue

Comment: To add to the answer given by @trondhansen here's a great link for recommendations  http://homeaquaria.com/best-led-grow-lights-aquarium-plants/

Answer (score 1):

I got a ready-made setup of 7500K LED light with 6 blue LEDs.
It's giving very good results, but the only thing is blue light favours algae growth. That's the only factor which was killing my tank's beauty. If we increase the CO<sub>2</sub> in tank (go for pressurized), it will easily solve the algae problem of the tank. Addition of Flourish Excel will also boost the performance.

Note: This answer is from my own experience.